# AlertDialog with TextField in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need to get an alert dialog with three text fields, the following code works perfectly in the emulator.

The problem is that when I build the application in Release Mode and install the APK on my smartphone (Huawei P20 lite), or just run it in Release Mode, I get the result shown in the image below:

I just put the body code of the alert dialog:

[image: Screenshot of the alert dialog]

```
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  title: Text("Aggiungi alcolico al drink:"),
  content: Container(
    height:219,
    width:200,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:9.0),
        child: Expanded(
          child: Flexible(
            child: TextField(
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                controller: controller7,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8),),
                  ),
                  labelText: "Nome alcolico",
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:9.0),
          child:
          Expanded(
            child: Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: controller4,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8),),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Inserisci grado alcolico",
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:9.0),
          child: Expanded(
            child: Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: controller5,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8),),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Inserisci dose in ml",
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  actions: [
    okButton,
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app in debug mode and when something goes wrong, you see the scary red error screen with logs. In release mode, you just see a grey screen.

Now, when you ran your app in debug mode, at times there are some errors which are thrown but  mistakenly ignored as seen the app is running perfectly on screen but if you open your logs in debug mode, you will see some error messages. these error messages will cause problems like you experienced in release more

> but in case of your code this should work
> just remove the `Expanded` and `Flexible` widgets

**here is your fix :**

```dart
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Aggiungi alcolico al drink:"),
                content: Container(
                  height:219,
                  width:200,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:9.0),
                        child: TextField(
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                           controller: controller7,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8),),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Nome alcolico",
                          )),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:9.0),
                        child:
                        TextField(
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                           controller: controller4,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8),),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Inserisci grado alcolico",
                          )),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:9.0),
                        child: TextField(
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          controller: controller5,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8),),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Inserisci dose in ml",
                          )),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}),
                ],
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

hey there i believe that your problem is that u r using the predefined alert dialog which  you have used expandable and flexible on the same widget ,rather than that try to use only expandable and use flex keyword for defining the size of each widget . this might fix your problem ,,have fun coding;)